# Paypal Api. Switching from Sandbox to Live

Tags: paypal

Currently I have used the sandbox App Id and test credentials successfully to make API calls, however now I would like to switch to the live version. I looked at the check list and believe I switched out all the sandbox information to live credentials. However the last thing I need to switch out is the APP - ID. I created an App which has the status of "approved" in paypal developer however I'm not sure where to get the App - ID for it. In addition, should I be seeing the app in the Manage Classic Apps?  I see it in My Apps on the developer page, but not in that section. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select My Account > Profile > My Selling Tools, then click the Update (API Access) link
Click Request API Credentials on the API Access page
Select Request API signature and click Agree and Submit to generate a set of Signature credentials

More information can be found at: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/

EDIT:

You will need to use the classic api to obtain an APP-ID. The new API does not use APP-ID's, but instead client ID's which are extremely different.

Comment: Hey Justin, thanks for the help. I already switched out my sandbox credentials with those credentials. My question was how would I get the live App Id for my application I created in developer.paypal. Thank you very much. As of right now I need to switch out that global APP - ID used for testing.

Comment: Edited. Any questions, let me know.

Comment: Thats a great answer and just what I was looking for. thank you Justin. Well I guess I'll create it on the classic :). If I do have any other questions. I'll be sure to contact you.

Comment: Forgot to mention, if you make an app using developer.paypal.com, you will not see it in the classic app section. Those are created at apps.paypal.com

Comment: I had one more question. is the creation and sending of invoices existing only in the Classic API as of right now? I don't see the option within the REST API

Comment: I was wondering if you had any insight on the other questions I posted.